# What is the use of the `Know someone who can answer?` function?

Tags: discussion, sharing

Surely if I knew someone who could answer the question, i would contact them directly and not post the question? The only reason I can understand why *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook."* is in there is so that others can see the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is used to share the question in social networks, namely Google+, Facebook, and Twitter, in addition to letting you share the question via email.

Apart of email, it's not like you directly know someone who can answer, but by sharing in your social network there is always a chance someone who is following you might know the answer and come to save the day.

Comment: Oh, so you don't actually send it to someone's profile, you actually publicly post it so everyone can see? If so, isn't this labelled a bit odd, it makes you think that you link it to one direct person.

Comment: Also, very nice website! Wow!

Comment: @NebulaeGuy you post it on your own Wall/Profile/Account, yes. As for public or not, guess it depends on each site's settings.

Comment: Thanks, what website? If you mean Lazy Loaders (formerly Developer Barn) it's not mine but thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Answer (score 2):

I always assumed this feature is not for the use of the asker of the question, but for people who view it.

If I see your question, but can't answer it myself,  I might know someone who could answer your question,  and this feature lets me  share the question with that person.